# Would a moon that is tidally locked to a gas giant rotate at an axis?

Tags: moons, tidally-locked, axial-tilt

Can a tidally locked moon have an axial tilt and have seasons like Earth?

If not, what if the gas giant was tilted. Would the moon follow its tilt?

Comment: You may want to include a simple graphic or two to explain what you mean.  I think I understand, but the brevity of the question makes the meaning challenging. You may also need to specify other details about the system, like "where does the heat and light come from?"

Comment: From what i found the first may be impossible. And i am not sure if the second would change anything

Comment: Please remember that asking more than one question, no matter how seemingly related, is literally a reason to vote to close a question. I need to leave the answer to this post to one of our celestial machinists. I'm pretty sure that the definition of "tidally locked" doesn't allow for the locked object to have an axial tilt (otherwise it's not really locked).  Note that you have a complexity that bears thought: seasons are the result of a sun (or heat/light emitting object), so a moon with an axial tilt would only have seasons based on the star the planet orbits. OK, continued comment...

Comment: ... or, possibly, the gas giant. However, while the gravitational tidal forces of a gas giant can heat a moon (e.g., Io), that's not sunlight/light, which is required to make seasons. In short, no light, no seasons, regardless of axial tilt. I hope that made sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminology note first: [axial tilt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_tilt) is the angular difference between a body's axis of rotation, and axis of orbit. [Orbital inclination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_inclination) is the angular difference between a body's axis of orbit and its *parent's* axis of rotation.

Moons of gas giants often end up in synchronized (eg. tidally locked) circular orbits with low or zero inclination and axial tilt. But that does not mean they can't have seasons! If their parent body has an axial tilt, then a moon which has an axial tilt of 0° and an inclination of 0° *relative to its parent* will be inclined *relative to the sun*, and that angle is what generates seasons.

For an extreme example of this, consider [Uranus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranus), which has an axial tilt of 82.23°. Its moons (eg. [Titania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titania_(moon)#Orbit), with an inclination of 0.34° and an axial tilt of basically zero) orbit its equator, almost at right angles to Uranus' own orbital plane, and so for decades at a time the poles of those moons will be in continuous sunlight and then for decades again they'll be in continuous darkness... this kind of change in illumination over the course of the parent body's year is clearly seasonal.

[Titan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon)) has an axial tilt of zero and an orbital inclination of ~0.35° relative to Saturn, but as Saturn has an axial tilt of ~27° Titan experiences [noticable seasonal climatic effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_Titan#Seasons). Additionally, because of [Saturn's own orbital eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn#Orbit_and_rotation) (0.0565, more than 3 times that of Earth), there's about a 12% difference in Titan's distance from the Sun during Saturn's year, and this will drive seasonal effects even in the absense of any tilt or inclination.

Not all moons end up in these neat orbits about their parents, Consider like Neptune's moon [Triton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triton_(moon)#Capture), which was probably captured into an irregular orbit which then circularized and its rotation was synchronized by tidal forces over a long period of time. Triton therefore has an inclination of 156.885° relative to Neptune's axis. Such a moon *could* have seasonal changes, even if its parent had 0 axial tilt and orbital eccentricity.

Answer (score 0):

Moon needs not follow planet's axial tilt even when tidally locked. Earth's Moon  for example has almost no tilt relative to Sun and [thus it does not have seasons](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3541/are-there-seasons-on-luna). If it had then yes it would have seasons.